# Python list cross-identification (overlap?) by specific equation

Tags: python, numpy, match, overlap

I have a cross-identification problem on data with 2 axes like

```
A = array([['x0', 'y0', 'data0', 'data0'],
           ['x0', 'y0', 'data0', 'data0'],
           ['x0', 'y0', 'data0', 'data0']])

B = array([['x1', 'y1', 'data1', 'data1'],
           ['x1', 'y1', 'data1', 'data1'],
           ['x1', 'y1', 'data1', 'data1']])
```

What I need is to find the rows of 2 lists that have the same `position`. The `position` needs to be discribed as their `distance` is close enough, which is:

```
distance = acos(cos(y0)*cos(y1)*cos(x0-x1)+sin(y0)*sin(y1))
if(distance < 0.001):
    position = True
```

Currently, I use a code like below:

```
from math import *
def distance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    a = acos(cos(y1)*cos(y2)*cos(x1-x2)+sin(y1)*sin(y2))
    if(a < 0.001):
        return True
    else:
        return False
f = open('cross-identification')
for i in range(len(A[0])):
    for j in range(len(B[0])):
        if(distance(A[0][i],A[1][i],B[0][j],B[1][j])==True):
            print(A[0][i],A[1][i],A[2][i],B[2][j],A[3][i],B[3][j],file=f)
        else:continue
```

It's OK with a few rows, but the problem is that I have MASSIVE data and the speed is extremely slow. Are there any ways that can make it quicker?

BTW I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343010/cross-identification-overlap-of-two-lists-in-python-by-common-identifier), close to what I want but I can't just change it. Maybe I can get some help from u?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order not only to avoid the expensive Haversine formula but also to open up the option of using KDTrees, I'd recommend translating to Euclidean coordinates and distances.

```
def to_eucl_coords(lat, lon):
    z = np.sin(lat)
    x = np.sin(lon)*np.cos(lat)
    y = np.cos(lon)*np.cos(lat)
    return x, y, z

def to_eucl_dist(sphdist):
    return 2*np.arcsin(sphdist/2)
```

KDTrees are easy to use, here is a skeleton which should get you started.

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree

eucl_1 = np.c_[to_eucl_coords(lat1, lon1)]
eucl_2 = np.c_[to_eucl_coords(lat2, lon2)]
t1, t2 = KDTree(eucl_1), KDTree(eucl2)
neighbors = t1.query_ball_tree(t2, threshold)
```

Comment: Thx a lot! This is working on my code. But I have a question is that the threshold here `neighbors = t1.query_ball_tree(t2, threshold)`, refers to the max distance right? So what unit is it in? By defining the `to_eucl_dist()` function or just in a unit of degree?

Comment: @X.Yang it should be the Euclidean distance, so apply `to_eucl_dist` to your threshold. But you'll see they're almost the same (`0.001` and `0.00099999996`).

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I made it clear. The two arrays I have are with 25,000 rows. The old way I use cost about 30mins. With your method, it only cost 3 seconds. Thank you again, Paul!

Answer (score 0):

This is a performance problem.  You have plenty of low hanging fruits for huge improvement in your distance function.

1. instead of `acos(x) < eps` use `x > 1 - (eps**2)/2` that saves you an expansive `acos()` (this works because of Taylor Expansion), obviously precompute `1 - (eps**2)/2`
2. instead of computing `cos(y0)` etc `4*len(A[0])*len(B[0])` times, pre-compute them which takes only `2*(len(A[0])+len(B[0]))` times which saves you many many trig computations if `A*B` gets large
3. seems to me precomputing `cos(x1-x2)` is also a win, but I'm not 100% sure

That's just slightly optimizing each distance evaluation.  I think a bigger problem is your double loop is making N*M evaluations.  Ideally you can reduce that loop with some smart geometric algorithm.  (see for example Computational Geometry by Mark de Berg et al, Springer 2008)

But your distance (metric) function is too bizarre!  I can't see how to transform your `(x,y)` to a space with that metric function.  I'm very curious where that distance function comes from.

Comment: Thanks a lot for advising!
I do want to reduce the loop, trying to have some numpy or pandas way but I didn't make it.
The function is a **spherical distance** function, calculating distance on a sphere surface.

Comment: You won't find simple answers in numpy, pandas or [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343010/cross-identification-overlap-of-two-lists-in-python-by-common-identifier](cross-identification (overlap) of two lists in Python by common identifier).  You need some 2D or ND algorithm similar to collision detection.  But first if you can spatial transform your problem so your metric function become more sane then directly calling a stock collision detection function may work.

Comment: Spherical distance!  COOL problem!  I will give it some more thought on the bus.

Comment: Also can you give a sense the sizes of `A` and `B`?  If in the thousands then EdR's answer would be fine, `np.meshgrid()` produce array size of millions which is no problem.  If `A` and `B` are each in range of millions then `np.meshgrid()` would blow up too.

Comment: The sizes of A and Bs are about tens thousand to hundreds thousand I think. I actually compare a lot of Bs to a single A, to see if any pairs of rows there. Sometimes I cut A to small pieces for different Bs to reduce the waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic outer product type problem: compare each combination of two vectors.

The previous answer is correct that your double loop is killing efficiency. A possible answer is to use numpy

Depending on the size of your inputs, you could use a [meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) approach or (more complicated) the numpy universal functions with [outer product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html).

For the former you could try something like:

```
import numpy as np
A = [[1, 1],
     [1, 3],
     [3, 1],
     [3, 3]]

B = [[1, 1],
     [3, 1],
     [1, 2],
     [1, 3],
     [3, 3]]

a_array = np.array(A)
b_array = np.array(B)

x0, x1 = np.meshgrid(a_array[:, 0], b_array[:, 0])
y0, y1 = np.meshgrid(a_array[:, 1], b_array[:, 1])

distance = np.arccos(np.cos(y0)*np.cos(y1)*np.cos(x0-x1)+np.sin(y0)*np.sin(y1))
good_pairs = np.nonzero(distance < 0.001)

print(distance)
print(good_pairs)
for b_ind, a_ind in zip(*good_pairs):
    print('Entry {} of A ({}) matches entry {} of B ({})'.format(a_ind, A[a_ind], b_ind, B[b_ind]))
```